# Find vectors length

Tags: vectors

Calculate $\|\boldsymbol{c}\|$ if $\mathbf c= 2\boldsymbol{a} \times \boldsymbol{b}$ and $\boldsymbol{a} = 3\hat{\boldsymbol{k}} - 2\hat{\boldsymbol{j}}$ and $\boldsymbol{b} = 3\hat{\boldsymbol{i}} - 2\hat{\boldsymbol{j}}$.

Can't find vectors length.

Comment: Can't you write the borders using mathjax?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the cross product?

Comment: tag algebraic-geometry doesn't seem suitable for this problem

Comment: @Nenq Here's a little overview of [how to use MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  To get $|x|$ type `$|x|$`.  To get $\|x\|$ type `$\|x\|$`.  To get $\vec c = 2\vec a \times \vec b$ type `$\vec c = 2\vec a \times \vec b$`.  In the future try to format your questions using this so that it's easier for us to read.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I am new here.

Answer (score 2):

So we have:

$$c = 2\overrightarrow{a} \times \overrightarrow{b} $$

$$=2\det \begin{pmatrix}i & j & k \\ 0 & -2& 3 \\ 3 & -2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=2\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 9 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 18 \\ 12 \end{pmatrix}$$

where I used the cofactor expansion about the first row to take the determinant and now the length is given as:

$$\|c\| = \sqrt{12^2 + 18^2 + 12^2}$$

Comment: I am so stupid, i thought that "x" was missing variable, not multiplication sign. :D

Comment: I would say that if you see two vectors on both sides of the "x", assume that it is a cross product.

Answer (score 0):

Ya so we start the vectors are $6k-4j$ and $3i-2j$ so we need to take cross product which is given by determinant form . I hope that you know that basics of vectors so we get $c=18j+12k$ thus its mod is $2\sqrt{117}$ . Please share your effort next time as you are new here.